# get generic type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I need a function to return some of "default" values for a type.
Say, I want -1 for integers, "none" for strings, MyEnum.DefaultValue for an enum...

I started from the following problem to implement a generic function for the code bellow:
[image]

(`.value` is of 'string' type that I try to convert to strings, numbers or booleans)

```
public getPropertyValue<Type>(propertyCode: string, properties: PropertyValue[]): Type {
  return <Type>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode)?.value || defaultValue);
}

public async calculate(properties: PropertyValue[]): Promise<CalculatorResult[]> {
  const STA = <EnumSTA>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'STA')?.value || EnumSTA.NF_EN_1992_1_1_NA);
  const FYK = <number>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'FYK')?.value || 0);
  const CON = <EnumCON>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'CON')?.value || EnumCON.C3037);
  const BCO = <number>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'BCO')?.value || 0);
  const HCC = <string>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'HCC')?.value || 'none');
  const GTC = <number>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === 'GTC')?.value || 0);
```

I want to write a generic function that would return me the default type value, like this

Some pseudo code bellow:

```
public getDefaultValue<Type>(): Type {
  switch(typeof (Type)){
    case 'boolean': return false;
    case 'number': return -1;
    case 'string': return "none";
    case 'EnumCity': return EnumCity.Paris;
  }
}
```

what closest real variant of that function is possible with Type/Java/Script?

PS.

Suppose I have the full list of possible types, so, I could create something like this, that compiles well in TypeScript:

```
getPropertyValue<Type extends (string | number | boolean | EnumCity)>()
{
   return <Type>(properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode)?.value);
}
```

Comment: You can't. The types are erased at compile time, you don't have access to switch a value at runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. You're trying to use a type as a value, `Type` won't exist at runtime because JavaScript doesn't support it.

Comment: Just an FYI, `typeof (new EnumCity())` will be `'object'` at runtime. - Also the method given doesn't take any parameters. Where is `Type` defined?

Comment: Still not clear. It supports the _values_ of booleans, obviously `true` and `false` both exist. It doesn't support the _type_ of `boolean`, that gets erased. If you had a _parameter_ you could check the type of that value at runtime, but the generic goes. Maybe use e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ to explore what's emitted.

Comment: @serge no `typeof (false)` will be `'boolean'`. Currently `typeof (Type)` will throw an error, since `Type` is not defined.

Comment: To put it another way, if you want e.g. `expect(getDefaultValue<boolean>()).toBe(false)`, note that the actual JavaScript that executes is just `expect(getDefaultValue()).toBe(false)` - how's it supposed to know which branch you wanted?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a step back to the context - how do you imagine using this? _Is_ `getDefaultValue<boolean>()` the kind of thing you're intending? Right now it seems like you're unclear on what TypeScript actually _is_.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] the question and include your actual usecase for such a function.

Comment: @JonasWilms I updated the OP to explain the initial problem

Comment: @jonrsharpe, updated the OP to better explain the existing problem. I have a lot of functions calls I would like to rewrite as a function

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. But it's the same problem I outlined above - think about what's in the emitted JavaScript, there's no value whose type can be checked at runtime.

Comment: May you swap the picture for text?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so, in other words, there is no way to rewrite the function in the picture?

Comment: I can't draw on the text to show what goes where, so I added also the text, and the picture

Comment: No, there isn't. You could write something that enforced the right type for a default value, which helps a bit - `getProperty<number>(properties, 'STA', 0)`. But also: _"`.value` is of 'string' type that I try to convert to strings, numbers or booleans"_ - not in what you've posted, you don't. [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) are **not** casting or conversion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added a PS to OP, where I try to enumerate all possible types, that compiles in TypeScript...

Comment: Yes it compiles, but it's useless. Worse than, even; all it succeeds in is suppressing the fact that your function could return `undefined`. Again, type assertions aren't conversions (and they _can't be_, because again you need to think about what _actually runs_). Also you should add return types to your functions.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is transpiled into JavaScript, and JavaScript will not know about the `T` in `getPropertyValue<T>`, since all type annotations are erased from your TS code when it is transpiled into JS.

I'd suggest you rewrite your `getPropertyValue` to accept another parameter that will be used as the default value when needed. Much like Java's [`getOrDefault`](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/library/hashmap/getordefault) convention or Rust's [`unwrap_or`](https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/e4.unwrap_and_expect.html#unwrap-or-unwrap-or-default-and-unwrap-or-else).

```js
public getPropertyValueOrDefault<ValueType, DefaultType = ValueType>(
    propertyCode: string,
    properties: PropertyValue[],
    defaultValue: DefaultType
): ValueType | DefaultType {
    return (
        properties.find(
            x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode
        )?.value as ValueType ?? defaultValue
    );
}
```

Notice that the `property.value as ValueType` is a [footgun](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17393292). If I understood your question correctly, `property.value` is actually always a `string`. Then the only type safe option is to have different getter functions for different types:

```
public getBooleanPropertyOrDefault(
    propertyCode: string,
    properties: PropertyValue[],
    defaultValue: boolean
): Boolean {
    const value = properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode);
    return typeof value === "undefined" ? defaultValue : Boolean(value);
}

public getNumberPropertyOrDefault(
    propertyCode: string,
    properties: PropertyValue[],
    defaultValue: number
): Number {
    const value = properties.find(x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode).value;
    return typeof value === "undefined" ? defaultValue : Number(value);
}

// And so on
```

Or even something like my preferred solution to avoid the cognitive load with long function names:

```js
public getProp(code: string, props: PropertyValue[]) {
    const value = props.find(x => x.propertyCode === propertyCode).value;
    return {
        or: <T extends string | number | boolean>(dflt: T): T => {
            if (typeof value === "undefined") return dflt;
            switch(typeof dflt) {
                case "string": return String(value);
                case "number": return Number(value);
                case "boolean": return Boolean(value);
            }
        },
        asBoolOr: (dflt: boolean) => Boolean(value ?? dflt),
        asNumberOr: (dflt: number) => Number(value ?? dflt),
        asStringOr: (dflt: string) => String(value ?? dflt),
        parseOr: <T>(parser: (value: string) => T, dflt: T) =>
            typeof value !== "undefined"
                ? parser(value)
                : dflt,
    };
}
```

Which you'd then use as

```js
const STA = getProp("STA", properties)
    .parseOr(/* parseSta */, EnumSTA.NF_EN_1992_1_1_NA);
const FYK = getProp("FYK", properties).or(0);
```

Comment: so the generics are useless, if we need to specify when calling the function along the type also it's default value (type dependent)...

Comment: finally, I resigned to rewrite my function, left it as is

Comment: @serge I wouldn't call the type system useless — vice versa actually. It's just that it's not meant to influence the flow of the program concretely, but only to _guide you_ as the programmer. I'll add a version to the last example in my answer that you might find more useful, just a moment